# NameError: name 'audio_path' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to set up this guitar tab transscriptor, but ran into a problem with the path not being defined. As you can see in the code, i tried to set the path to `r'C:\Users\Bruger\Desktop\GuitarSet\audio\audio_hex-pickup_original'` and so on. I don't have that much coding experience, and was simply just following an online tutorial, but i would really like to know whats wrong here. Thanks in advance

```
path = r'C:\Users\Bruger\Desktop\GuitarSet\audio\audio_hex-pickup_original'
    audio_file = os.listdir(path)
    audio_path = os.path.join(path, audio_file[file_num])


    # Function for removing noise
def cqt_lim(CQT):
        new_CQT = np.copy(CQT)
        new_CQT[new_CQT < -60] = -120
        return new_CQT

    # Perform the Constant-Q Transform
data, sr = librosa.load(audio_path, sr = None, mono = True, offset = start, duration = dur)
CQT = librosa.cqt(data, sr = 44100, hop_length = 1024, fmin = None, n_bins = 96, bins_per_octave = 12)
CQT_mag = librosa.magphase(CQT)[0]**4
CQTdB = librosa.core.amplitude_to_db(CQT_mag, ref = np.amax)
new_CQT = cqt_lim(CQTdB)  

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
**NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-144a3248f390> in <module>
     14 
     15  # Perform the Constant-Q Transform
---> 16 data, sr = librosa.load(audio_path, sr = None, mono = True, offset = start, duration = dur)
     17 CQT = librosa.cqt(data, sr = 44100, hop_length = 1024, fmin = None, n_bins = 96, bins_per_octave = 12)
     18 CQT_mag = librosa.magphase(CQT)[0]**4
NameError: name 'audio_path' is not defined**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it has to do with the indentation of `audio_path` and `audio_file`.

Is it possible to see some previous code?

Comment: The only code before that are imports of tensorflow :). Yeah i also had to mess a little around with identation, but i'm not sure how to space it if thats the problem.